# How do i limit the number of concurrent maximum connections on a Wi-Fi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I'm trying to limit the amount of unspecfied connections on a given router from 15 to 20 users at a time.

I've tried DHCP limiting where the available IP address range is limited from 0 users to around 20. Although this kind of works, it dosent allow new connections once user IP addresses have been established.

In other words, if the DHCP range is set to 20 users, only the initial set of 19 unspecified users can connect at a time, and all new connections trying to access the router will be refused.

Although this works in theory, it turns out that if one of the initial current set of users turns of or disconnects from the WIFI, another device cannot connect to it. And it's only when the router reboots, that assigned IP addresses will be refreshed and a new set of users can connect.

Is there a way to allow brand new connections beyond the initial 19/20 set of connected devices to join the Wi-Fi network without rebooting the router? So far it seems the only way to limit the number of maximum connections on a network is by DHCP IP limits or Subnet mask.

Both of these methods require rebooting of the Wi-Fi router to allow for new connections to join, despite old connections being disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Most (virtually ALL) SOHO equipment will not have any provision for this.
High end (think very expensive WLAN controllers) equipment usually has features for this, but is out of range for most of us, unless you are in a big corporate environment.

As you already realized the best you can do is limit the size of the DHCP scope to the desired maximum number of clients.

However there is another thing you must do for make that work properly: You need to reduce the DHCP lease-time to a very short period, because the DHCP server will not re-cycle free addresses until AFTER their full lease-time has expired.

A lot of SOHO routers will default to 1 day or 1 week lease-times. But you can usually set the lease-time to something like 15 minutes.
Setting it even lower is not a good idea. The network-stack in many clients doesn't really like it if it gets any shorter, which may lead to stability issues for your clients.